# Oreki and Chitanda's relationship in the anime Hyouka

Tags: hyouka

I can't stop thinking  of  what happens between Oreki and Chitanda after the last episode of the anime. Does  anyone  know what happens in the 5th volume of the manga, with regards to Oreki and Chitanda?

Comment: Do you mean the 5th volume of the novels? The 5th manga volume is just the second half of the movie arc.

Comment: Been wondering exactly the same thing, Lovely anime with a lovely story, but the ending keeps me puzzling. I really want them to be together, but the anime ended rather unclear about the "romance" between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Hyouka anime and manga is actually based on the light novel series named ‘**Classic literature club**’.  The manga adaptation haven’t even caught up to the anime ( please update me when it does ) . However, in the light novel their relationship is progressing with similar pace as in the anime. None have till now confessed their feeling to oneself or to each other. Oreki seems way more comfortable around Chitanda though.

Comment: no it is part of said franchise series, not based on it.

Answer (score -1):

It may be in the future they may become girlfriend and boyfriend due to how their relationship was so i think that's my answer but i don't think they'll get married yet maybe in a couple years time they will but i guess only time will tell

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.